# Marquee is not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am working on this site: http://kolkata-web-design.co.in/MAX/.

I have made a marquee tag in the red strip to show scrolling text "welcome to max group". It is shown in all browsers but not in Internet Explorer.

Comment: marquee is just wrong, stop now before you want to use blink.

Comment: In IE 8 it is working, which version of IE do you have?

Comment: Also works in Chrome.  There are a lot of reasons why you shouldn't use `marquee`, not the least of which is that it's removed from the HTML standard.

Comment: Worked in IE7-10 for me.

Comment: it works here in IE7,IE8 and IE9

Comment: @dagon: consider the horror of a blinking marquee... with animated gif background and auto-play .wav. It'd be as if myspace got busy with geocities and had a child.

Comment: "The Cheapest Website Development Company in Kolkata" -- all is explained.

Comment: Why not actually help OP instead of bashing like righteous zealots in the process of expiation?

Comment: You might want to add a <blink> tag around the marquee to make it really pop

Comment: @somdeb : Why dont use accept answers ? and by the way , i hope you include SO in the credits , since you seem to be dumping all your doubts here , without doing any hard work on your own. and btw, horrible design

Comment: Marquee tag is a bad idea, but is it really a reason to vote to close? As far as I can tell the question is valid.

Comment: @Juhana : I rather suspect the user is trying to promote his site. look at all his previous questions. instead of putting up code ,  he will paste the link to his site.

Comment: @CyprUS Then it should be flagged to report spam (or the link edited out), not closed as "not constructive".

Answer (score 3):

As several people (including me) have observed that the marquee text works on IE, I suspect that this is about a setting on the IE you are using. At least if I go to Internet settings, Advanced settings, under Multimedia there is a checkbox for allowing animations. Apparently marquee is counted as animation in this sense, since when I checked the checkbox off (it is on by default) and restarted IE, the marquee text is not there (not even as static text).